# Show that sequences satisfying these two conditions need not be and must be Cauchy, respectively

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Given a sequence $(a_n)$ prove that

a) If it is known that $|a_{n+1}-a_n|< 1/n$ for all $n$, show that $(a_n)$ *need not be* a Cauchy Sequence.

b) If it is known that $|a_{n+1}-a_n| < 1/2^n$ for all $n$, show that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy Sequence.

Do I prove it using the definition of Cauchy sequence i.e for a) I've tried to find $\epsilon$ such that $|a_{n+1}-a_n| > \epsilon$ but failed.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You do not need $|a_{n+1}-a_n|>\varepsilon$, but $|a_p-a_q|>\varepsilon$ for some $p,q$ going to infinity.

Comment: The problem is not formulated correctly. Let me try to fix it.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/why-doesnt-dx-n-x-n1-rightarrow-0-as-n-rightarrow-infty-imply-x-n) for a).

Comment: Check this steps to reach the answer[Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661047/cauchy-sequences-involving-geometric-series/661121#661121).

Answer (score 6):

I suspect there is confusion about understanding the problem. The problem is really asking you whether you are allowed to conclude that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy if *all you know* is the inequality as stated.

Thus, in order to solve (a) you must find a *particular concrete sequence* which satisfies the condition but is not Cauchy. In order to solve (b) you must show that *every sequence* satisfying the condition is Cauchy. So, here are the solutions:

(a) We must give a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < 1/n$ *and* the sequence $(a_n)$ is not Cauchy. Here is one: define $a_n = 1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n$. Then for all $n$ we have
$$|a_{n+1} - a_n| = 1/(n+1) < 1/n,$$
however, as is well known the sequence $(a_n)$ is divergent (it is known as the *harmonic series*).

**NB:** There are sequences which satisfy $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < 1/n$ but are Cauchy. For instance, the sequence $a_n = 0$ is Cauchy and $|a_{n+1} - a_n| = |0 - 0| = 0 < 1/n$.

(b) We must show that *every* sequence $(a_n)$ which satisfies $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < 1/2^n$ is Cauchy. Proof: suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < 1/2^n$ for all $n$. 
To prove that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, consider any $\epsilon > 0$. We must find $N$ (depending on $\epsilon$ only) such that $|a_m - a_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n, m$ satisfying $m \geq n \geq N$. We claim that $N = 1 + \log_2 \epsilon$ is good. As in @HeeKwonLee's answer, we may compute that for all $m \geq n \geq N$ we have
$$|a_m - a_n| < 1/2^{n-1} \leq 1/2^{N - 1} = 1/2^{\log_2 \epsilon} = \epsilon$$

Answer (score 2):

a) $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k}$ so that it satisfies the condition.
To prove that $\{ a_n\}$ is not Cauchy, what must we do ?

b) $$|a_{m}-a_n| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^m |a_k-a_{k-1}| = \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}
          <\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} $$
Can you find an $\epsilon$ ?